# How to enable MP3 encoding feature for Speech-to-text API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

For the Google Cloud `Speech-to-text` api, the encoding of `MP3` is supported but it is under a beta. As stated here:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding

When I try to send a request with the encoding set to `MP3`, I get an error response of `Invalid value at 'config.encoding' (TYPE_ENUM), "MP3"`.

Do I have to enable this beta feature somewhere? And if so, where can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using the v1 and not the v1p1beta1, the MP3 encoding is there in v1p1beta1. [Reference](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/speech)

[image: v1]

[image: v1p1beta1]

Comment: Correct. I noticed they mention it in the release notes too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in recognitionconfig, set proper encoding and samplerate, see [Reference for mp3](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig#AudioEncoding)